# What happens if I enable secure boot on a dual boot system?

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a laptop in a dual boot environment. To install wifi-card drivers, Ubuntu is asking me to enable dual boot with a password of some kind.

I get that this is to embed some keys to sign the driver in the firmware if I got it right?

So my question is really: What happens if I do this and what happens to the Windows part of the laptop?

Comment: It's actually simpler to disable Secure Boot (the message shows up because you have it enabled and has nothing to do with dual-boot). You can disable Secure Boot if using Windows 10 or older. If using Windows 11 then you must follow the MOKutil instructions to indeed sign the proprietary drivers.

Comment: So say that i were to follow the MOKutil instructions, it wouldn’t affect windows ability to boot in any way?

Comment: Absolutely not. It has NOTHING to do with dual-boot.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification!